# How to force users to complete their profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-2.0

I have designed a **learning management system** that customers can attend courses, buy books and ... .
In this system when users want to enrollment in course forced to fill their profile info. But some of them don't want to enrollment in course and then I can't have their info.

**I want to force users to complete their profile and enter the required information into their profile.** For example I want:

> System show them warning and force them to complete their profile three days after registration.

How can I do that? 
Notice: In other hand I want to block access for users who have not yet completed their profile to use the panel, until they complete theirs profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement a middleware. In this [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/) you will get your user and check if they have a profile, if not then redirect them to the profile page with a message for example.

You middleware would look something like this

```
def check_userprofile_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        If not hasattr(request.user, "profile"):
             redirect("complete-profile-page")

        response = get_response(request)

        return response

    return middleware
```

Then you need to add this to your middlewares section in settings.py to activate the middleware.

Hope this helps!